# Store access_token in the AsyncStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, react-native

After user enters `ID` and `password`, I am passing `access_token` from Rails.

I am using
[itzikbenh/Rails-React-Auth](https://github.com/itzikbenh/Rails-React-Auth) and 
[itzikbenh/React-Native-on-Rails](https://github.com/itzikbenh/React-Native-on-Rails) as reference.

But I am unable to save the `access_token`. Here is the code:

```
let res = await response.text();
if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    //Handle success
    let accessToken = res;
    console.log(accessToken);
    //On success we will store the access_token in the AsyncStorage
    this.storeToken(accessToken);
    //this.redirect('home');
    alert(ACCESS_TOKEN )
} else {
    //Handle error
    let error = res;
    throw error;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AsyncStorage.setItem` to store single items:

```
import { ... AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'

try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('access_token', access_token);
} catch (error) { // Error saving data }
```

Then to retrieve it use `AsyncStorage.getItem`:

```
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access_token');
  if (value !== null) console.log(value)
} catch (error) { // Error retrieving data }
```

For storing and retrieving multiple items you can see [AsyncStorage.multiSet](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#multiget) and [AsyncStorage.multiGet](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html#multiset).